# How do I pass custom values.yaml to Helm via Ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install Helm charts from local path via ansible using the following module:

```
- name: Deploy Elasticsearch chart from local path
    community.kubernetes.helm:
      name: es
      chart_ref: ./elasticsearch
      kubeconfig_path: ./kubeconfig
      release_namespace: elasticsearch
      create_namespace: true
```

The chart is present in the directory `./elasticsearch` and this method by default refers to the values.yaml. But I want the chart to refer to a file that was created with custom values (custom-values.yaml). How do I force the helm module in ansible to use the `custom-values.yaml` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/helm_module.html) you are looking for the 'values_files' parameter.

```
- name: Deploy Elasticsearch chart from local path
    community.kubernetes.helm:
      name: es
      chart_ref: ./elasticsearch
      kubeconfig_path: ./kubeconfig
      release_namespace: elasticsearch
      create_namespace: true
      values_files:
      - /custom-values.yaml
```

should do the trick for you

Comment: Thanks a ton! This works. Not sure how I missed this in the documentation :/